# Moodle plugin as exe file

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I was trying to create windows .exe file to install moodle local plugin.
Is this doable installing plugin with .exe file?
Appreciate your suggestions. Reference to documentation access!

Comment: installs are usuallly file copies, config, and database mods. A script that mimics the normal install is likely to be easier (since OS security policies etc will likely restrict exe whereas scripts can usually do those things. try .bat or .ps on windows or python, or .sh on linux

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install Moodle? There are packages available for installing Moodle on a Windows machine:

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Complete_install_packages_for_Windows

Otherwise, using an exe to install a local plugin doesn't make any sense. You just need to copy the code to the local folder. Or unzip the code into a local folder.

Then either upgrade via your site `yourmoodlesite/admin/` or use the command line:

```
php admin/cli/upgrade.php
```

See https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Administration_via_command_line#Upgrading

Comment: Its not moodle installation. I already developed a moodle local plugin. I want make this plugin as .exe file.The exe file should install the plugin in moodle.

Comment: Could you explain why it is not doable to make an Windows .exe

Comment: Why do you want to use an exe though? You just need to copy the PHP code.